# Есть некая последовательность из цифр. Нужно найти участки неубывания и нужно пропускать следующий за участком элемент

Tags: python

У меня есть последовательность: 3, 5, 4, 2, 1, 4, 6, 1, 0
Мне нужно вывести последовательность: 3,5; 2; 4,6; 0. Нужно пропустить 4,1,1.
По заданию нужно пропускать следующий за участком элемент. Элементы идут по возрастанию, 4<5, значит следующий анализ начать нужно с 2, а не с 4. и т.д
Я написал как не пропускать такие элементы, а как пропустить я не пойму.
Буду благодарен за помощь!
Вот мой код (и то скорее всего он не правильный):

```
result = []
podspisok = []
previous_number = None
for current_number in seq:
    if previous_number is None or current_number > previous_number:
        podspisok.append(current_number)
    else:
        result.append(podspisok)
        podspisok = [current_number]
    previous_number = current_number
if podspisok:
    result.append(podspisok)
print(result)
```

Comment: То есть у вас есть последовательность чисел (если они однозначные, то это еще не повод их цифрами называть), и вам нужно выделить строго (или нестрого - об этом вы не сказали) возрастающие фрагменты особым способом: первое число после очередного фрагмента пропускается, и следующий фрагмент начинается со второго числа после этого фрагмента. То есть для [0 1 2 0 1 2 0] результатом должен быть список [[0 1 2] [1 2]]. У вас проблема в том, что вы выделяете [[0 1 2] [0 1 2] [0]], верно?

Comment: @EzikBro Мне нужно выделить нестрого возрастающие фрагменты, т.е участки НЕУБЫВАНИЯ ( если Вы про это). Да, Вы правы. Нужно пропустить элемент после такого фрагмента и начать со второго. Да, именно, у меня такая проблема(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> и то скорее всего он не правильный

Надо быть более уверенным в себе, я всего пару ваших строк поправил

```
seq = [3, 5, 4, 2, 1, 4, 6, 1, 0]
result = []
podspisok = []
previous_number = None
for current_number in seq:
    if previous_number is None or current_number >= previous_number: # нестрогий знак
        podspisok.append(current_number)
        previous_number = current_number # разделил по веткам присваивание
    else:
        result.append(podspisok)
        podspisok = [] # число, которое меньше предыдущего добавлять не нужно в следующий фрагмент
        previous_number = None # и так как оно пропускается, считаем, будто его и не существует
if podspisok:
    result.append(podspisok)
print(result) #[[3, 5], [2], [4, 6], [0]]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!